# Booting Linux with Root Filesystem via NFS: Loops on "Sending DHCP and RARP requests ..."

Tags: linux, embedded, beagleboneblack, nfs, u-boot

I'm trying to boot the Beaglebone Black with the kernel still on my host machine via NFS.  I'm under the impression that it is not necessary for my host machine to be a DHCP server, and that manual IPv4 static IPs are sufficient.  The boot process ends up looping on the following:

```
[  357.280386] IP-Config: Retrying forever (NFS root)...
[  357.285865] net eth0: initializing cpsw version 1.12 (0)
[  357.393659] SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720 4a101000.mdio:00: attached PHY driver 
[SMSC LAN8710/LAN8720] (mii_bus:phy_addr=4a101000.mdio:00, irq=-1)
[  357.412716] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  360.563747] cpsw 4a100000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  360.572294] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  360.593014] Sending DHCP and RARP requests .....
```

Relevant bootargs/bootcmd:

```
U-Boot# echo $nfs_bootcmd                                                      
tftp 0x81000000 zImage; tftp 0x82000000 am335x-boneblack.dtb; bootz 0x81000000 - 0x82000000

U-Boot# echo $bootargs   
root=/dev/nfs rw ip=192.168.0.100:192.168.0.1:::eth0:off console=ttyO0 nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/nfsroot nfsrootdebug

U-Boot# echo $ipaddr     
192.168.0.100

U-Boot# echo $serverip   
192.168.0.1
```

My /etc/exports:

```
/nfsroot *(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

Here is the serial output during boot: [Linux boot via NFS](https://pastebin.com/5qC06hMc).

HW/SW Setup:

- Beaglebone Black
- Ethernet connected from host directly to target board (no router/switch/hub in between)
- tftp working fine
- rootfs seems to mount fine through NFS
- Host machine is NOT setup as a dhcp server
- u-boot/Linux

Is it necessary to make my host machine a dhcp server?  How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by setting up a DHCP server on my host machine.  After installing isc-dhcp-server (on Ubuntu), I modified /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf to look like so:

```
# /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.0.0 192.168.0.254;
}

# the host name doesn't need to match anything.
host beaglebone {
    # MAC address from U-boot's ethaddr env var
    hardware ethernet 04:a3:16:f5:1a:56;

    # The static IP to be allocated to the beaglebone device
    fixed-address 192.168.0.100;
}
```

This solved the issue and the device boots up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use NFS to boot your device while retaining a static network configuration rather than having to use DHCP.

Using what you have provided above, it would be similar to something like this.

```
U-Boot# echo $nfs_bootcmd                                                      
tftp 0x81000000 zImage; tftp 0x82000000 am335x-boneblack.dtb; bootz 0x81000000 - 0x82000000

U-Boot# echo $bootargs   
root=/dev/nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.1:/nfsroot,nolock,nfsvers=3 nfsrootdebug nfsaddrs=192.168.0.100:192.168.0.1::255.255.255.0:::none rw console=ttyO0

U-Boot# echo $ipaddr     
192.168.0.100

U-Boot# echo $serverip   
192.168.0.1
```